# Can't retrieve correct time from database

Tags: java, mysql

I have fields startTime and endTime in my table with type as time. When I try to retrieve it with query it gives wrong values of time even if the data table values are correct.
The query is as follows :

```
SELECT
    ts.id,
    ts.serviceRuleId,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ts.startTime, '%h %i %p') AS tempStrtTime,
    FROM_UNIXTIME(ts.endTime, '%h %i %p') AS tempEndTime,
    ts.createdBy,
    ts.createdOn,
    ts.startDate,
    ts.endDate
FROM
    TemporaryTimeSlots AS ts
GROUP BY
    ts.id
```

Comment: does this query gives desired result when run directly in mysql prompt ? If yes then show the code you have implemented.

Comment: @JammuPapa it is not giving desired result in mysql prompt

Comment: then simply your query have some problem, you need to fix that first :)

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using the `FROM_UNIXTIME` etc.

You are using Java, so use the `SQL.Date` object and you will get the correct result

```
select ts.id, ts.serviceRuleId,ts.startTime as tempStrtTime, ts.endTime as tempEndTime, ts.createdBy, ts.createdOn, ts.startDate, ts.endDate from TemporaryTimeSlots as ts group by ts.id
```

Comment: Time is saved in 24 hour format and I want to retrieve it in 12 hour format with am/pm

Comment: then use SimpleDateFormat, you retrieve the Date as is, then use a SimpleDateFormat to reformat it to whatever you want in Java. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html